# Plugin or advice on how to parse XML in real-time?

Tags: plugins, xml

I am working on a project for my university basketball team. During each game their statistics software will create an XML file and update it mid-game with player statistics, shots, etc.

What I would like to do is to display this content in a post during the games so that media members could have access to it. I'd like to be able to link to the XML file and then have the post update when changes are made or the other option is to update it on a frequent basis to make sure the statistics are up to date.

How can I do this? I've tried the plugin *WP All Import* but it requires a paid version to do chron updates.

Comment: This could help: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-heartbeat-api-getting-started/

Comment: Welcome to our site! I took the plugin recommendation part out of the question, because that is off topic here. Take a look at the solutions for [How can I avoid code duplication for a blog with lots of source code?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118721/how-can-i-avoid-code-duplication-for-a-blog-with-lots-of-source-code) They are probably related to your task.

Comment: If the paid version works for your needs then just buy it, you can use your time for other things. As there is an actual full plugin that does it, it indicates that it is not a very simple thing to do and you will have to break this big question into smaller parts. One will probably be a php related question about importing and parsing XML files and the other will be a wordpress related about how to display the result of the processing on your site.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thank you all for your help. I apologize for not responding earlier. I went ahead and got the pro version and it is working perfectly. Good advice.

Answer (score 3):

You could the following to achieve this in the "WordPress way":

- Add code via [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) or [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- In the code add a [wp cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) task
- The task should get the file with [wp_remote_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get)
- Parse the xml file with [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)
- Update the content to meta fields of the post with [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)
- You could display the meta fields and the post with [the_content filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) or [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)